# How to kick FollowupEvent from dialoflow webhook in Golang

Tags: go, dialogflow-es

I am not familiar with Go. Could you tell me how to build correct structure of dialogflow.GoogleCloudDialogflowV2WebhookResponse for Followup event.

The following code is not working:

```
return dialogflow.GoogleCloudDialogflowV2WebhookResponse{
    FollowupEventInput: &dialogflow.GoogleCloudDialogflowV2EventInput{Name: "event-follow"},
}
```

Answer (score 0):

solved:

foovar:= &dialogflow.GoogleCloudDialogflowV2EventInput{
        LanguageCode: "en",
        Name:         "nextevent-follow",
        Parameters:   []byte(messages),
    }